# Output array to Plugin::log

Tags: plugin-development, logs

Just wondering if its possible to output an array to the Plugin::log call? Would be really handy to see if an error occurs, what a data object's values are!

Tried the following:

```
Plugin::log(array('test')), LogLevel::Error);
Plugin::log(json_decode(array('test')), LogLevel::Error);
Plugin::log(var_dump(array('test')), LogLevel::Error);
Plugin::log(print_r(array('test')), LogLevel::Error);
Plugin::log(\CVarDumper::dump(array('test')), LogLevel::Error);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing `true` as the second parameter to [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) returns a string that can be written to the log.

```
Plugin::log(print_r(array('test'), true));
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Plugin::log(\CVarDumper::dumpAsString(array('test')), LogLevel::Error);
```

Note the `\` in front of `CVarDumper` to tell PHP that class is not in the Craft namespace, but in the global one.

Comment: Looks good, but the following error ```Fatal error: Call to undefined method CVarDumper::export()```

Comment: My bad... I guess I should actually read the error message.  It's `dump`, not `export`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Haha, yeah thats better :) Still outputs a blank row in the log ```2015/02/27 23:12:37 [error] [plugin] ```

Comment: I think the example might be missing a parenthesis at the end of the first argument: `\CVarDumper::dump(array('test'))`

Comment: Thanks Ben, in practice its correct. In fact, it outputs the array to the screen, just not in the log file. This might be a devMode things though...

Comment: Didn't realize dump echo'd out the results.  dumpAsString will work writing it to the log, though... just tested it.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that works a treat as well! Too bad I can't mark both answers as accepted :)